# Table border OnlyOutsideEdges

Tags: html

Following code is okey.

```
<style>
  table {
     border-bottom: 2px solid black;
     border-top: 2px solid black;
     border-left: 2px solid black;
     border-right: 2px solid black;
  }
</style>
</head>
```

How to shorten above code something like;

```
<head>
<style>
 table {border-OnlyOutsideEdges: 2px solid black;}
</style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/2mr0p2qL/)

You could combine your styles, and make it shorter as below.

```
<head>
  <style>
    table {border: 2px solid black;}
  </style>
</head>
```

Please read more about border in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border)

Answer (score 0):

Change table {border-OnlyOutsideEdges....} to this:

```
<style>
table {outline: 2px solid black;}
</style>
```

OR:

```
<style>
table {border: 2px solid black;}
</style>
```

Learn more about borders [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)